Napkin exercise 54.2.7
Let $K$ a number field and $x\in K$. Then exists $n$ such that $nx \in \mathcal O_K$. The exercise asks us to prove this, and gives two different suggestions about how to do it. One of them is by using the minimal polynomial. I found it straightforward to prove it that way, and it even feels like it might generalize to other fields of fractions of other integrally closed domains. The other suggestion is to "take the norm". I don't see any way the norm would be helpful in proving this. Can i have a hint?

@peterag I don't see why multiplying $y/z$ by the norm of $z$ gives an algebraic integer.

@peterag Oh, i see. For the non-Galois case. $Nz$ is still an element of $\mathcal O$, and so is $z$. Therefore $z' = Nz / z$ must also be in $\mathcal O$. Is this correct? This also seems to give an alternative proof that every separable quadratic extension is Galois!

@peterag Oops, right, i know $\mathcal O$ is a field, that was a mistake. So to sum up. $Nz/z$ is in the ring of integers of the Galois closure of $K$, therefore it is an algebraic integer, but it is also in $K$ therefore it is in $\mathcal O_K$, right?

@peterag One equivalent definition of $Nz$ is the product of all galois conjugates of $z$. And clearly the galois conjugate of an algebraic integer is again an algebraic integer. Is that what you mean by knowing it "directly"?

To summarize comments (both  the OP's, and mine, now deleted) - and to take this off the unanswered queue:
Suppose $x= y/z\in K$, with $y,z\in {\cal O}_K$. Set $n= Nz$, where $N$ is the $K$ norm. Given that $n\in \mathbb Z$, the idea is to show that $Nz = z\cdot z'$, with $z'{\in \cal O}_K$, so that
$$ n x = z \cdot z'\cdot  (y/z)= z'\cdot y \in {\cal O}_K.$$
Fix an algebraic closure $\overline K$ of $K$. According to 'one of the equivalent definitions of the norm,' (as per the OP in the comments), $$Nz=\prod \sigma z,$$  where $\sigma$ runs through the embeddings of $K$ into $\overline K$. In particular, $Nz = z\cdot z'$, with  integral $z'\in \overline K$, as a conjugate of $z$ is also integral. On the other hand both, $Nz$ and $z$ are elements of $K$, so that $z'=Nz/z$ is also an element of $K$. Hence $z'\in {\cal O}_K$.
Obviously, this is no longer a 'hint'...
